# Visual force + Extension = Can't display values?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

Working on a PDF report using Visualforce.  Earlier questions answered here  ([LINK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70530/controller-extension-help)) but now I'm stuck again.

I have two child objects off of Account.

- Issue (Issue__c)
- Filing (Filing__c)

The report runs from Issue, but needs to get the related Filing records from the related account. I've tried multiple times but I can't seem to add anything in *filings* or filings2 to the visualforce output.

Visualforce Page

```
<html>
    <head>            
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Summary Page for Branch Analyst</p>

        <tr>
            <td>Issuer</td>
            <td>{!issue__c.Issuer_Name__r.name}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Par Amount</td>
            <td><apex:outputtext value="{0,number,$#,###,###}"><apex:param value="{!Issue__c.Par_Amount__c}"/></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue Description</td><td>{!issue__c.Issue_Description__c}</td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of Bid Sale</td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!Issue__c.Date_of_Bid_Sale__c}"/></apex:outputText></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Is the Issue subject to 15c2-12?</td>
            <td>{!issue__c.Is_the_Issue_subject_to_15c2_12__c}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>{!Firm.name}</td>
```

**This is where it fails**

```
            <td>Filing Name</td>
            <td>{!Filings.name}</td>

        </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here's the extension**:

```
public with sharing class FICMSummaryPDFController {
    public Issue__c issue { get; private set; }
    public account firm { get; private set; }
    public List <Filing__c> filings { get; private set; }
    public List <Filing__c> filings2 { get; private set; }

    public FICMSummaryPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        issue = (Issue__c)controller.getRecord();
        firm = [SELECT Name,(SELECT ID from FinancialFilings__r) from account where ID = :issue.issuer_name__c];
        filings = (firm.FinancialFilings__r == null) ? new List<Filing__c>() : firm.FinancialFilings__r;
        filings2 = [select id, name from filing__c where issuer__c = :issue.issuer_name__c];        
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filings` and `filings2` are both `list<Filing__c>` - so you would need to iterate over it to get a list output.

You can't just access `{!filings.Name}`

If you are going to get a list of many filings, you should have a look at `<apex:repeat>` or `<apex:pageblocktable>`

Or if you just want to have the first element of the list, you could try it with

```
 public Filing__c filing { get; set; }
```

and in the constructor

```
 filing = filings[0];
```

or the same with `filings2`. You should also check that you have at least one record in `filings` and/or `filings2` and `filing` doesn't get null. Otherwise  `{!filing.Name}` (note singular!) will end-up in an exception.

Also it looks like you are missing the `<table>` tag in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @uweheim!
After some additional review (and coffee) I ended with this, which is working, however, I would be open to additional input?

VF

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @page {size: portrait; margin: .25in;}
            p {font-weight: bold; text-align: center;}
            table {width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; page-break-inside: avoid; margin-bottom: 15px;}
            td {vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; }
            th {vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; }


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Summary Page for Branch Analyst</p>

        <tr>
            <td>Issuer</td>
            <td>{!issue__c.Issuer_Name__r.name}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Par Amount</td>
            <td><apex:outputtext value="{0,number,$#,###,###}"><apex:param value="{!Issue__c.Par_Amount__c}"/></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue Description</td><td>{!issue__c.Issue_Description__c}</td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of Bid Sale</td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!Issue__c.Date_of_Bid_Sale__c}"/></apex:outputText></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Is the Issue subject to 15c2-12?</td>
            <td>{!issue__c.Is_the_Issue_subject_to_15c2_12__c}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>{!Firm.name}</td>
        </tr>


        <p>Audited Financials and Operating Data</p>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finFilings}" var="fFile" >
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.name}" HeaderValue="Filing"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Filing_Name__c}" HeaderValue="Year"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Date_rating_required__c}" HeaderValue="Date Required"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Date_financials_filed__c}" HeaderValue="Date Financials Filed"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Finding__c}" HeaderValue="Finding"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Date_Op_data_filed__c}" HeaderValue="Date Op Data Filed"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!fFile.Op_data_status__c}" HeaderValue="Finding"/>                    
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <p>Material Events</p>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ratFilings}" var="rFile" >
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.name}" HeaderValue="Filing"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.Rating_change__c}" HeaderValue="Up/Downgrade"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.Date_of_change__c}" HeaderValue="Date of Change"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.Date_rating_required__c}" HeaderValue="Date Required"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.Date_filed__c}" HeaderValue="Date Financials Filed"/>
                <apex:column value ="{!rFile.Rating_finding__c}" HeaderValue="Finding"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </body>
</html>
```

APEX

```
public with sharing class FICMSummaryPDFController 
{
    public Issue__c issue { get; private set; }
    public account firm { get; private set; }
    public List <Filing__c> finFilings { get; private set; }
    public List <Filing__c> ratFilings { get; private set; }

    public FICMSummaryPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {

        issue = (Issue__c)controller.getRecord();

        firm = [SELECT Name,(SELECT ID from FinancialFilings__r) from account where ID = :issue.issuer_name__c];

        finFilings = [select Filing_Name__c, Date_rating_required__c, Date_financials_filed__c, Finding__c, 
                      Date_Op_data_filed__c, Op_data_status__c, id, name 
                      from filing__c where issuer__c = :issue.issuer_name__c order by filing_name__c desc]; 

        ratFilings = [select Rating_change__c, Date_of_Change__c, Date_Rating_required__c, Date_filed__c, Rating_finding__c, id, name 
                      from filing__c where rating_issuer__c = :issue.issuer_name__c order by filing_name__c desc]; 

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You should really move this as an edit to the original question as Uwe provided the answer; and 2) a better long-term design would be to do the SOQL in the getters for each `List<Filing__c>` - this way if any updates are done, you are refreshing the latest version of the lists; it also means the controller can be reused for other pages and hence the constructor doesn't fetch anything; only pages that reference a given controller property will fetch the records.

Comment: Thanks @crop1645  I'm never sure if significant updates should be added to a thread or if a new question is needed.  As far as your answer, I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @uweheim answer, your controller would be better constructed as:

```
public with sharing class FICMSummaryPDFController {
 public Issue__c issue { get; private set; }
 public account firm { 
  get{  return [SELECT Name,(SELECT ID from FinancialFilings__r) 
                  from account where ID = :this.issue.issuer_name__c];}
  private set; }
 public List <Filing__c> finFilings {
   get {return [select Filing_Name__c, Date_rating_required__c,
                       Date_financials_filed__c, Finding__c, 
                       Date_Op_data_filed__c, Op_data_status__c, id, name 
                  from filing__c 
                  where issuer__c = :this.issue.issuer_name__c
                  order by filing_name__c desc];}
   private set; }
 public List <Filing__c> ratFilings { 
    get {[select Rating_change__c, Date_of_Change__c, 
                 Date_Rating_required__c, Date_filed__c, Rating_finding__c,
                 id, name 
              from filing__c 
              where rating_issuer__c = :this.issue.issuer_name__c 
              order by filing_name__c desc]; }
    private set; }

 public FICMSummaryPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    issue = (Issue__c)controller.getRecord();
 }
}
```

This is a better long-term design: Do the SOQL in the getters for each List - this way if any updates are done in page processing in the future, you are refreshing the latest version of the lists; it also means the controller can be reused for other pages and hence the constructor doesn't fetch anything that isn't needed for the page at hand, improvinf performance; only pages that reference a given controller property will fetch the records